# can I EXCLUDE rows in my complex query where criteria is met? (combining WHERE + multi AND)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to get results from a table where the grouped IDs exist in rows where field1 = a and field2 IS NOT NULL, but NOT rows where field1 = b and field2 IS NULL.  just getting syntax error, don't know quite how to combine these criteria...

here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT a.post_title AS title, a.id,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'endorser' THEN b.meta_value END) endorser,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'trail' THEN b.meta_value END) trail,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'townarea' THEN b.meta_value END) townarea,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'state' THEN b.meta_value END) state,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'start-date' THEN b.meta_value END) startdate,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'description' THEN b.meta_value END) description,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'organizer-name' THEN b.meta_value END) organizer,
     MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'info-email' THEN b.meta_value END) infoemail
     FROM wp_posts a LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
     WHERE b.post_id IN 
        (SELECT Post_id FROM wp_postmeta 
         WHERE (meta_key = 'endorser' AND meta_value IS NOT NULL) 
         AND (meta_key = 'trail' AND meta_value IS NULL)) group by b.post_id
```

AND the table looks something like this:

```
meta_id  |   post_id   |  meta_key  |   meta_value
---------|-------------|------------|------------
  1      |     53      |  endorser  |   joe
  2      |     54      |  trail     |   trail name
```

So I would get rows containing post_id 53, but NOT 54

I'm very tired, so I may be missing something simple, like a simple OUTER JOIN?

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5420/1

Comment: What do you get as result?

Comment: As a result, I SHOULD get all the rows where the id exists in the list of rows that have a value associated with "endorser" but not rows where there IS a value associated with "trail" - I just edited the question to reflect that - i get a syntax error trying it the way it's written

Comment: I need the LEFT join to get the title from the related table

Comment: if you want only value associated endorser then you can remove the second condition in your select statement, and for the syntax error you are missing a closing `)` for you SELECT subquery and as @SajithNair said use INNER JOIN you will still get the title

Comment: that COULD work if I didn't want to EXCLUDE the ids where gtrail MUST be empty.  see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5420/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of your subquery by using `b.meta_key  IN ('endorser','trail')` and in where clause you can use `CASE` for your is null and is not null criteria

```
SELECT a.post_title AS title, a.id,
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'endorser' AND post_id =a.id) endorser,
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'trail' AND post_id =a.id) trail,   
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'townarea' AND post_id =a.id) townarea,   
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'state' AND post_id =a.id) state,   
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'start-date' AND post_id =a.id) startdate,   
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'description' AND post_id =a.id) description,   
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'organizer-name' AND post_id =a.id) organizer,   
(SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'info-email' AND post_id =a.id) infoemail   
     FROM wp_posts a 
     LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
 WHERE b.meta_key  IN ('endorser','trail')
     AND (
  CASE
    WHEN b.meta_key = 'endorser' 
    THEN b.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
    WHEN b.meta_key = 'trail' 
    THEN b.meta_value IS NULL 
  END
)
HAVING trail =''
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5420/12)

Comment: Oddly, this returns 1 result, where there should be more than 50

Comment: @DavidMcClave again a fiddle demo would be helpful if you can provide

Comment: making a fiddle demo now

Comment: @DavidMcClave [*See fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5420/2) it is getting one row

Comment: It SHOULD be getting 3 results in this example - id 1386, 1388, and 1390

Comment: @DavidMcClave according to criteria in where it get 5 records [*see fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5420/4),select ids if b.meta_key = 'endorser' then value should be not null if b.meta_key = 'trial' then value should be null right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49374/discussion-between-david-mcclave-and-m-khalid-junaid)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use LEFT JOIN, use INNER JOIN

```
FROM wp_posts a INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
```

Comment: returns no results when I should have more than 50